# Question regarding Lagrange polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $x_0<x_1<\ldots<x_n$ be $n+1$ distinct points in $\mathbb{R}$. Define polynomials $\ell_0,\ldots,\ell_n$ of degree $n$ by $$\ell_j(x):=\prod_{k\neq j}\frac{(x-x_k)}{(x_j-x_k)}.$$ Let $P_n=\mathbb{R}_n[x]$ be the polynomials of degree $\leq n$ which is a vector space of dimension $n+1$.
Show that the $n+1$ polynomials $\{\ell_0,\ldots,\ell_n\}$ are basis for $P_n$, i.e., they are linearly independent. This is known as the Lagrange basis for $P_n$ (for the points $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n$).
Well this part is easy enough and can be seen [here](http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/geoffp/lm-ss/lectp10.pdf)

Find the coordinates $[f]_B$ of polynomial $f\in P_n$ with respect to the basis $B = [\ell_0,\ldots,\ell_n]$.
Not too sure how to do this one. Any advice would be great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Simply $(f(x_1); f(x_2), \cdots)$ ...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to find scalars $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n$ such that $f \in P_n$ can be written as
$$f = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j \ell_j,$$
that is, for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\displaystyle f(x) = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j \ell_j(x).$
Note that, for $x_k$, where $k$ is between $0$ and $n$, we need that
$$f(x_k) = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j \ell_j(x_k) = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j \delta_{jk} = a_k$$
where $\delta_{jk} = 0$ if $j \neq k$ and $\delta_{jk} = 1$ if $j=k$. Hence, the desired scalars $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n$ are simply
$$f(x_0), f(x_1), \dots, f(x_n).$$

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in the definition of  Lagrange polynomials:
$$\ell_j(x):=\prod_{k\neq j}\frac{(x-x_k)}{(x_j-x_k)}.$$

**Hint**:

A polynomial of degree $\le n$ is uniquely determined by its values at $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n$.

On the other hand, the $\ell_j$ satisfy the properties
$$\ell_j(x_j)=1,\quad \ell_j(x_k)=0\enspace(k\ne j).$$
Can you fond a linear combination of the $\ell_j$ which take the same values as $f$ at $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n$?